# How to render/parse ansible output using json_query, getting null value

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, ansible-template, json-query

I have below output3.msg, how to get the desired output mentioned below? Please help in the syntax, check the one i have and suggest any modifications.I am in learning phase apologies for any mistakes Thank you.

output3.msg

```
    {
        "msg": [
            {
            "auto_key": {
                    "proxy_id": {
                        "entry": [
                            {
                                "local": "1.1.1.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY1",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.0.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "1.1.2.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY2",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.1.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "1.1.3.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY3",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.2.0/24"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "copy_tos": "yes",
                "name": "customer-a",
                "tunnel_interface": "tunnel.5",
                "tunnel_monitor": {
                    "enable": "no"
                }
            },
            {
             "auto_key": {
                    "proxy_id": {
                        "entry": [
                            {
                                "local": "2.2.1.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY1",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.3.0/24"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "copy_tos": "yes",
                "name": "customer-b",
                "tunnel_interface": "tunnel.10",
                "tunnel_monitor": {
                    "enable": "no"
                }
            },
            {
               "auto_key": { 
                    "proxy_id": {
                        "entry": [
                            {
                                "local": "3.3.1.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY1",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.4.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "3.3.2.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY2",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.5.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "3.3.3.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY3",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.6.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "3.3.4.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY2",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.7.0/24"
                            },
                            {
                                "local": "3.3.5.0/24",
                                "name": "PROXY3",
                                "protocol": {
                                    "any": null
                                },
                                "remote": "192.168.8.0/24"
                            }                        
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "copy_tos": "yes",
                "name": "customer-c",
                "tunnel_interface": "tunnel.15",
                "tunnel_monitor": {
                    "enable": "no"
                }
            }
       
    
     ]
        }
```

desired output

```
    {
            name:customer-a,
            local:1.1.1.0/24,1.1.2.0/24,1.1.3.0/24,
            remote:192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,
            tunnel: tunnel.5
                    
    },
    {
            name:customer-b,
            local:2.2.1.0/24,
            remote:192.168.3.0/24,
            tunnel: tunnel.10
                    
    },
    {
            name:customer-c,
            local:3.3.1.0/24,3.3.2.0/24,3.3.3.0/24,3.3.4.0/24,3.3.5.0/24
            remote:192.168.4.0/24,192.168.5.0/24,192.168.6.0/24,192.168.7.0/24,192.168.8.0/24,
            tunnel_interface: tunnel.15
                    
    }
```

my debug syntax

```
       - debug: msg="{{output3.msg|json_query(jmesquery)}}"     
         vars:
             jmesquery: "[*].{Name: name, local: proxy_id.entry.local,remote: proxy_id.entry.remote,tunnel:tunnel_interface}"
```

output i'm getting

```
"msg": [
    {
        "Name": "customer-a",
        "local": null,
        "remote": null,
        "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
    },
    {
        "Name": "customer-b",
        "local": null,
        "remote": null,
        "tunnel": "tunnel.10"
    },
    {
        "Name": "customer-c",
        "local": null,
        "remote": null,
        "tunnel": "tunnel.15"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `null` values is because `proxy_id.entry` is an array and it doesn't have `local`/`remote` keys directly under it. The correct syntax would be something like `proxy_id.entry[].local`.

Using `auto_key.proxy_id.entry[]` syntax in `json_query` produced the desired output. Below is the task:

```yaml
    - name: show jsondata
      debug:
        var: output3.msg | json_query(jquery)
      vars:
        jquery: "[].{Name: name, local: auto_key.proxy_id.entry[].local | join(',', @), remote: auto_key.proxy_id.entry[].remote | join(',', @), tunnel: tunnel_interface}"
```

Note that I have used `join()` function to get comma separated string for `local` and `remote`. Below is the output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output3.msg | json_query(jquery)": [
        {
            "Name": "customer-a",
            "local": "1.1.1.0/24,1.1.2.0/24,1.1.3.0/24",
            "remote": "192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "customer-b",
            "local": "2.2.1.0/24",
            "remote": "192.168.3.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.10"
        },
        {
            "Name": "customer-c",
            "local": "3.3.1.0/24,3.3.2.0/24,3.3.3.0/24,3.3.4.0/24,3.3.5.0/24",
            "remote": "192.168.4.0/24,192.168.5.0/24,192.168.6.0/24,192.168.7.0/24,192.168.8.0/24",
            "tunnel": "tunnel.15"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I modified your JSON structure to make it valid (answer updated), and then it works fine. If this not matching what you have, then please correct the JSON data posted in your question.

Comment: you are right i made a typo while copy pasting, `proxy_id` is under `"auto_key": {` i have edited the question, does now `local: proxy_id.entry[].local | join(',', @)` becomes `local: auto_key.proxy_id.entry[].local | join(',', @)` ???

Comment: Yes, that's correct. you need to use `auto_key.proxy_id.entry[].local`. I updated the answer.

Comment: now getting below error :
`FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function join(), invalid type for value: 1.1.1.0/24, expected one of: ['array-string'], received: \"AnsibleUnsafeText\""}`

Comment: worked now, jsut did some modifications in output but syntax is right as you suggested, thanks for your help.